# Get the words from a string with jQuery regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

The content is brought dynamically so I need to be able to put in a ordered list on the fly..

Currently, it's bringing in my text like this with the white-spaces:

```
<div class="born">BORN RESIDENCE PLAYS FAVORITE</div>
```

This is the intended format I am trying to accomplish but no luck..

```
<div class="born">
  <ul>
   <li>BORN</li>
   <li>RESIDENCE</li>
   <li>PLAYS</li>
   <li>FAVORITE</li>
 <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a less hacky way, but:

```
var text = $("div.born").text();
var textArr = text.split(" ");
$("div.born").html('<ul></ul>');
$.each(textArr, function (k, v) {
    $("div.born ul").append('<li>' + v + '</li>');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KKauk/

Comment: its formating it like this:<div class="born">
     <ul>
       <li>BORN RESIDENCE PLAYS FAVOURITE</li>
        <li>SURFACE IDOLS HEIGHT WEIGHT STATUS RACELIST</li>
        <li>RANKING CLOTHING SHOES</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

Comment: That means the `.split(" ")` isn't working - the returned strings aren't spaced with `&nbsp;` are they?

Comment: No, its just blank spaces. I'm in wordpress and pulling in the text from <?php the_content(); ?> I am however removing the <p> tags with: remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); not sure if that is causing the issue.

Comment: So, the issue was the way the text was formatted in the post. I had to have it like this: <div class="born">BORN RESIDENCE PLAYS FAVOURITE SURFACE IDOLS HEIGHT WEIGHT STATUS RACELIST RANKING CLOTHING SHOES</div> Side by side. Before I was breaking the words... THANKS AGAIN!!!

Comment: Grim-I ended up using your solution. I got hung up again when applying this method to multiple divs..Any how ideas on how I would apply this? This is what I have which is a bad approach, but it works...                        var text0 = $('#d0').text(); 
    var textArr0 = text0.split('*');
    
    var text1 = $('#d1').text(); 
    var textArr1 = text1.split('*');
    
    var text2 = $('#d2').text(); 
    var textArr2 = text2.split('*');

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get words from a string with jQuery (and a little bit of javascript):

```
 var splitted = str.split(/\s+/);
```

- `\s` - Match blank space.
- `+`  - Match one or more times.

[jQuery match all words in string](http://jsfiddle.net/VYGpt/7/)

```
var str = $('div').text();

var splitted = str.split(/\s+/);
var _ul = $('<ul/>');
$('div').html(_ul);
$.each(splitted, function(key, value) {
    $(_ul).append($('<li/>').html(value));
});
```